# Python copies/duplicates object rather than instantiates a default one

Tags: python-3.x, oop

First off, I'm relatively new to Python, so pardon the rough code I have. Here goes: I have a class with a constructor. It inherits a few properties from a superclass. This same class can also be a child object of itself. So an Epic can hold an Epic, which I'm appending to the Children property as a list.

```
class Epic(V1Superclass):
    Type = 'Epic'
    Children = []
    ParentAssetID = []


    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key == 'Name':
                self.Name = value
            elif key == 'Description':
                self.Description = value
            elif key == 'Super':
                self.Super = value
            elif key == 'Scope':
                self.Scope = value
        if not bool(self.Super):
            self.Super = None
        if not bool(self.Scope):
            self.Scope = 445082
    def populateChildren(self,env,key):
        children = V1.utl.getChildren(env,key,'Epic',self.AssetID)
        for child in children:
            if child['_oid'].split(':')[0] == 'Story':
                print('Got another backlog child')
            elif child['_oid'].split(':')[0] == 'Defect':
                print('Got another Defect child')
            elif child['_oid'].split(':')[0] == 'Epic':
                
                childEpic = V1.Epic()
                        self.Children.append(childEpic)
```

If I create two instances of this class in the python console, everything's fine. I do "a = V1.Epic()" and "b = V1.Epic()", and the world is good. They all initialize to the proper default values (or empty). However, when I run my code in the populateChildren function, when I instantiate a new Epic object, rather than create a default version of the Epic, it is creating a new instance, but with all the properties of the parent (self) object. In essence, it's an exact copy, but if I do a "self is childEpic" command, it returns false, which (if I understand things correctly) means that childEpic is not a copy of the parent object. I can manipulate the child object and set properties with no problem, but obviously that's not how this should work. This is kind of maddening, as I'm not even sure what to google to see what I'm doing wrong syntax wise.

TIA!

I've tried adding an addChild function which tries to instantiate an instance outside the scope of the parent object, but even within that function, the object created is a duplicate of the parent

Comment: Do not make `Children` and `ParentAssetID` class attributes, since lists are mutable and will be shared by all instances of the class. Create those attributes in `__init__` instead.

Comment: *I do "a = V1.Epic()" and "b = V1.Epic()", and the world is good.* What is `V1`? What `V1.Epic()`? What has `a` and `b` to do with the class `Epic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` function is defined as a [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), which means that its first parameter is not a reference to the instance of the new object, but instead a reference to the current class. These properties are present on each of the class's instances, so it appears that they are being copied over.

Remove the `@classmethod` decorator from the `__init__` function and the `self` parameter will refer to the object being instantiated.

Comment: So I tried that, and that makes sense, but it still didn't do or change anything to what's going on. Still the same problem where the new instance is "the same" as the old.